# Mirroring raster using gdal_calc

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-calc

I am trying to flip (mirror) a raster upside-down. Using following command incoporating numpy function flipud()

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --calc="flipud(A)" --output output.flipud.tif
```

resulted with output.flipud.tif remains the same orientation as input. However, with

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --calc="fliplr(A)" --output output.fliplr.tif
```

results with output.fliplr.tif which is flipped left-right from the input.tif

Does anyone know why flipud() does not work in this case?

Comment: I even tried a hacked variation with `--calc="rot90(fliplr(rot90(A)),3)"` but still results in non-flipped raster. Amazing!

Comment: Make your TIFF a worlded TIFF (or BIL with the EHdr output type) then change the Y cell size in the companion world file (.tfw for TIFF and .hdr for BIL) to switch the sign, if it's positive make the value negative and visa versa. If then your hook point is bad you can change it in the world file. Much quicker than rewriting the whole image.